# Is it possible to pass a variable to control precision in printf?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I want to find a way around this, that is how to pass variable as precision control in printf?

```
printf "%7.5f\n" "$val" --> This is OKAY, I know
printf "%7.${NUM}f\n" "$val" --> Where NUM could be 2,3,4, or 5, etc.
```

Comment: You can also use the `*` modifier, just like in C. `printf "%7.*f\n" $NUM $val`

Comment: @rici Is this syntax correct then? `printf "%*.*f\n" $NUM1 $NUM2 $val`, if I want to change both `7` and `5`?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @daniel: sure. The `*` are replaced with arguments in order.

Comment: @chepner: OK, answer provided. FWIW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cleaner way to do it is to use the <kbd>*</kbd> modifier, just like in C.

```
$ for i in {0..5}; do
>   printf "%7.*f\n" $i 3.14159265358979323844
> done
      3
    3.1
   3.14
  3.142
 3.1416
3.14159
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I found this is a better solution as it can handle `awk` situation. For example: `num=3.1415926; prec=5; echo $num | awk -v vNum=$num -v vPrec=$prec '{ printf "%.*f\n", vPrec, vNum }'`

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me:

```
$ val=3.45678 NUM=3; printf "%7.${NUM}f\n" "$val"
  3.457
$ val=3.45678 NUM=4; printf "%7.${NUM}f\n" "$val"
 3.4568
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done:

```
val='15.23456'

NUM=5
printf "%7.${NUM}f\n" "$val"
15.23456

NUM=4
printf "%7.${NUM}f\n" "$val"
15.2346
```